# mnemonic.includes in not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-compile, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I've been trying to compile my solidity smart contracts So I'd be able to deploy them on the Ropsten Test network
when I run `truffle compile` I get this error :

> TypeError: mnemonic.includes is not a function at normalizePrivateKeys

I don't understand what this typeError means

here's the full message:

```
TypeError: mnemonic.includes is not a function
    at normalizePrivateKeys (C:\Users\aliya\node_modules\@truffle\hdwallet-provider\src\index.ts:62:38) 
    at new HDWalletProvider (C:\Users\aliya\node_modules\@truffle\hdwallet-provider\src\index.ts:102:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aliya\ethereum\supplychain\truffle-config.js:31:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at Object.require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Function.load (C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\index.js:161:1)
    at Function.detect (C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\index.js:150:1)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\compile.js:53:1)
    at Command.run (C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:136:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\cli.js:51:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:83:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:89:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

using Solidity 0.6.8

Truffle v5.1.26 (core: 5.1.26)

Node v12.16.2

and This is my truffle-config file:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider"); 
const Wallet = require("ethereumjs-wallet.js"); //this line gives

let mainNetPrivateKey = new Buffer(secrets.mainnetPK, "hex");
let mainNetWallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(mainNetPrivateKey);
let mainNetProvider = new HDWalletProvider(
  mainNetWallet,
  "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/***"
);

let ropstenPrivateKey = new Buffer(secrets.ropstenPK, "hex");
let ropstenWallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(ropstenPrivateKey);
let ropstenProvider = new HDWalletProvider(
  ropstenWallet,
  "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/***"
);


module.exports = {  
  networks: {

    development: {
      host: "localhost", // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 4465030, // Any network (default: none)
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: ropstenProvider,
      network_id: "3",
      gas: 4465030,
    },
    live: {
      provider: mainNetProvider,
      network_id: "1",
      gas: 7500000,
    },
   },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.8", 
      },

       }
    },
  },
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of thing that needs to be fixed

- From the hdwallet-provider [documention](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider#general-usage) the first parameter is the mnemonic or the private key. It will fail since you are passing a ethereumjs-wallet instance instead.
- From Truffle [documentation](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#providers) a provider should be returned by function. Passing an instance is not correct.

For example in case of ropsten something like this should work:

```
    ropsten: {
      provider: function () {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
          secrets.ropstenPK,
          "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/***"
        );
      },
      network_id: "3",
      gas: 4465030,
    },
```